# How do I repair my bootloader?

Tags: grub

My system has two Ubuntu installed, however, since the last install the system is booting to basic grub on booting. Using the boot-repair application I managed to get details:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BzCfWDZzVv/

Kindly let me know if there is something I can do to repair it.

Comment: You have mixed BIOS & UEFI installs. Your sda is BIOS/MBR and sdb is UEFI/gpt. Windows only boots from MBR in BIOS mode and only in UEFI mode from gpt. And you have BIOS boot loaders in sda and gpt's protective MBR on gpt drive which only exists to prevent old MBR partition tools from erasing gpt drive. You may be able to boot Ubuntu and should be able to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu is UEFI set for UEFI boot. And only boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode, Boot-Repair says you ran it in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree, my system was completely messed up, and in my defense, I will say I did not have (even now) time to overhaul the complete system.

The answer below took care of both the corrupted bootloader and change display resolution after installation.

So first few details: System have a 1TB harddisk and 256GB SSD

On the SSD was the initial Windows installation (UEFI), which I had to let go (means it is still corrupted).  So though it shows on the grub loader- the OS does not boot and give Window OS error.
There was Ubuntu 16.04 installation on the harddisk working perfectly.
I was interested in installing a new Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD, where earlier Ubuntu 16.04 was installed.

What finally worked (after trying boot-repair using [boot-repair live usb](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home)- app)):

1. Install Ubuntu through live CD on SSD (/sdb2 in my case) with boot loader on SSD.
2. Login to second Ubuntu (on hdd: /sda2) run `sudo update-grub` this will allow the grub bootloader to recognize 18.04
3. Next login to 18.04, while booting choose e to edit grub specifications add `pci=nomsi nouveau.modeset=0`
4. Install display drivers:

   - Use  `ubuntu-drivers devices` to first list all the drivers available for your GPU (I have GTX 1070 ).
   - Install the driver using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
5. Now reboot. And login back using the `e` option as before

Once you find all is working as expected- use Grub-customizer on Ubuntu 16.04 to modify the Grub.

P.S: I would like to have grub bootloader on SSD- but could not do it.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows.  So then you have to directly boot from UEFI boot menu. And part of issue is often Windows turns fast start up back on with updates and that sets hibernation flag which then prevents grub from booting it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  Use Boot-Repair's advance mode to install grub to any drive. But if UEFI, you must use gpt and have an ESP - efi system partition. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/